# Where can I post a question asking how much should cost a webpage?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any community out there where I can ask how much should cost a webpage? I really don't have anything else to turn to.

Comment: That's a question for user groups on Facebook, Google+, Reddit and similar...

Comment: If you can't put a price on something, please subcontract the work that way you will have all the information you need about the price.

Answer (score 9):

No, because the cost is largely variable.

By this I mean that the cost of *any* piece of software largely depends on what features are in it as well as what it actually *does*.  That costs development time, and we haven't even started looking at where it could be hosted.

To compound matters, the rates for developer time is variable across all developers and across all walks of the industry, so what may be $50/hr in one part could wind up being $90/hr in another or $30/hr in yet another.

Even if you added details to clarify and "nail down" a zone, it still remains a nebulous an ill-defined fact, which is subject to change every time the market decides to have a minor panic attack about the next DDoS attack, or gets a kick on the new web technology.

So...no.  You can't really ask that question of us here - we like questions which can be concretely answered - and there isn't another site in the network which would deal with such a topic, either.

Comment: And if you live in a low-cost country, where 1 dollar value's 4x, 10x or more of the local currency, you can charge $12/h and get big profits.

Comment: This is hardly an "answer." Rather a detailed explanation why questions like this are off topic here.

Comment: @JK.:  It has ***never*** been off-topic on Meta to ask where a question belongs on either Stack Overflow or elsewhere.

Comment: @Pekka웃 that reaaaally sounds like an apt description of an answer ;)